# Survey raw data

Tags: data-request, survey

I would like to perform some kind of analysis on survey raw survey data. That is on the actual answers, not on the processed results.

Where can I get such data?

Comment: http://asdfree.com

Comment: This is off topic here. It belongs on the [opendata.SE] SE site.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico - you should write http://www.asdfree.com/ as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Pew Research Center has a data site with downloads for many raw datasets from surveys and polling. Requires registration and license is for non-commercial use.

> Track key national, political, economic and demographic trends over time using our regularly updated charts and explore further by downloading our data sets, trying our data interactives or viewing our key data points.

- [Data site](http://www.pewresearch.org/data)
- [Downloads](http://www.pewresearch.org/data/download-datasets/)

Comment: Can you point a link for raw data? i.e the actual individual survey answers?

Comment: I guess they require registration now. http://www.pewinternet.org/datasets/february-2014-views-of-science-and-the-future/